# What should I do with the extra wire when intalling a new remote for my ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan

I am replacing a ceiling fan remote. the fan has 5 wires coming from it and the new receiver has 4 wires coming from it.  The old receiver had: fan out, common out, neutral in, live in and light out.  The new receiver has: line in, neutral in, light out and fan.  What do I do with the extra wire?

Comment: What is the make and model of the old and new remote modules? Can you include some photos?

Answer (score 1):

The "*Common Out*" lead on the old receiver module, is simply a grounded (neutral) conductor. Since the new receiver doesn't have this lead. You'll want to connect the white wire from the fixture, together with the white wire from the ceiling, and the white (neutral in) wire from the new receiver.

The new wiring should be connected as follows:

- Ungrounded (hot) conductor from ceiling to `Live In` wire on receiver.
- Grounded (neutral) conductor from ceiling to 'Neutral In`on receiver, and`Common` from fixture.
- `Light Out` on receiver to light (blue) wire on fixture.
- 'Fan Out` on receiver to fan (black) wire on fixture.
- All grounding (green, bare, etc.) conductors should be connected together, and connected to the ceiling box if it's a metal box.

<sup>***Notes:*** I've tried to keep the answer applicable to all areas, however, wire colors used in this answer are for the US and may be different in other countries.</sup>

Comment: It is very confusing in your answer to first be referring to the neutral wire as the grounded wire and then later referring to "All grounding conductors...".

Comment: @MichaelKaras That's the proper terminology. The proper term for the "neutral" wire is a *grounded* conductor, while the proper term for a "ground" wire is a *grounding* conductor.

Comment: It is still confusing. Especially for many of the folks that come to this site. I would stick with Neutral and leave it at that. You are making your answer more confusing than is even necessary to provide good guidance to the OP.

Comment: Michael, Tester is correct. The ground wire is technically called the "Equipment Grounding Conductor" and the neutral is referred to as the "Intentially Grounded Conductor". Job site slang has turned that into "ground" and "neutral".  If people want to do the work they should learn to do it right or leave it to the professionals. If the terminology is confusing to someone they need to learn more before attempting the work. Especially with electricity. ⚡️

Comment: I would add that Tester included the slang in parentheses in his answer. I don't know how you could make that any clearer while also educating the masses.  Tester